# How do I save a cookie throughout a session?

Tags: django

Suppose my django project gets some cookies from a server application (the webclient itself still gets django generated cookies). When I login django website, I ask for a cookie from that server application. It is currently saved in database, but we don't want this method.

My question is: does saving this cookie in request.session['special_cookies'] safe? How long does this information last?

What is a better way to save this information throughout browsing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's safe.  *It's still a database hit*, though: in the standard Django configuration, session data is pickled into a binary data field in the session.  It's just provided for you "out of the box" rather than your having to store it yourself.  You can improve performance by using the cached_db setting and giving memecache a lot of the details.

[RTFM, please.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: Thanks. This mind sounds stupid, but does calling request.session['special_cookies'] actually saves in the db? I have django.contrib.sessions enabled. I ask this because my goal is to access this special cookies in a non-view python file (lib.py, for example).

Comment: That accesses the db.  `request.session['special_cookies'] = { ... }` will cause a change, which in turn will cause a write-- which is two DB hits, by the way.  The code for contrib/Sessions is fairly readable, once you understand that a Session is a lightweight proxy that only reads from the db or cache when you call an accessor on it, and writes to the db or cache, if and only if you've made a change to it, when the response-stage middleware is triggered.